# Storing things for use later?

Tags: java, class, methods, interaction, construct

Is there any way that I could create a class in which something entered would be stored and be able to used later?
For example

> Coins class will construct a coin that has a name and a value. It will also have necessary accessor methods. Your Purse class (Driver class) will have some coins in it and you will print out how much money you have in the purse in a well formatted output.

if not, how would I go about doing this?

Comment: What do you mean by "later"? You mean after the program has exited, you return and get the same results as before, or just a simple way to store one data type inside another class? This seems like basic programming to me...

Comment: Persist your data in files, and give your classes the ability to read data from files and initialize themselves properly.

Comment: Have you learned about member variables?  Your purse HAS A array of coins.

Answer (score 0):

You can store information in variables and in member fields of a class:

I highly recommend checking out the official tutorial on [Classes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classes.html), which goes over member variables and how to use them.

```
class Example {

    int value;

    void setValue (int v) {
        value = v; // store value
    }

    void useValueForSomething () {
        System.out.println(value); // use it later
    }

    void localVariableExample () {
        int x = 42; // store x
        System.out.println(x); // use it later
    }

 }
```

If you mean that you want to information to persist across separate runs of your program (although I doubt you mean this), that is a broader and slightly more advanced topic; many techniques and frameworks exist to do that and you would have to ask a more specific question. However, it doesn't seem like this is what you mean, so I suggest checking out that tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Coin {
    String name;
    int value;
    Coin() {}
    Coin (String _name, int _value) {
        name = _name;
        value = _value
    }
    int getValue(){
        return value;
    }
}
```

Simple code for coin class.